# TypeScript tsc type check with references in monorepos

Tags: typescript, tsc, monorepo

I'm using Yarn Workspaces, and I want a cli-command to check the types of my source ts files located at `packages/*`.

Originally I build my project by using webpack (with esbuild, which does not check types) and check types with `tsc --noEmit` standalone. And they worked together very well.

After switching to Yarn Workspaces I splited my whole project into a couple of small packages.

The whole project is like this:

```
packages/
  foo/
    index.ts          // import bar from 'bar'; console.log(bar);
    package.json      // { "name": "foo" }
    tsconfig.json     // { "references": [ { "path": "../bar" } ] }
  bar/
    index.ts          // export default "hello world";
    package.json      // { "name": "bar" }
    tsconfig.json     // { "compilerOptions": { "composite": true } }
package.json          // { "workspaces": [ "packages/*" ] }
```

And then I found `tsc` failed to run. When I try `tsc --noEmit -p packages/foobar` it fails with a bunch of errors like:

```
Output file '/packages/foobar/index.d.ts' has not been built from source file '/packages/foobar/index.ts'.
```

However webpack works very well.

After surfing the internet, the official document tould me that those two feature could only be used in build mode. But when I tried `tsc --noEmit -b packages/foobar` it also fails due to conflicts between `--noEmit` flag and build mode. Moreover, if I removed `--noEmit` flag, `tsc` will try to generate a bunch of `.js` files for me but I don't want them to be generated.

I just want a cli-command to check types without outputing any extra files like what my IDE does. How can I run `tsc` correctly? or is there any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `typescript` as the dependency into `package.json` of the package you want to get checked.

(edit): also doesn't look like `tsc --noemit` works with project references...

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem, and "solved" by using [TS Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) and I added following to my `tsconfig.json`

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
  ...
}
```

This tells the Typescript compiler to not transpile any of the TS to JS but only emit the `.d.ts` declarations files.

Then in my `package.json` :

```json
scripts: {
   "lint": "tsc -b"
}
"
```

This will build any TS project references and the project you're running tsc in.  Though since we have 'emitDeclarationOnly' turned on, it'll only build declaration files for this proj.